# How can I use the JavaScript onchange event to submit a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, select, input, onchange

I have code like this:

```
<form action="checkin.php" method="post">
    <select name="roomname" onchange="???">
        <option value="">New Room:</option>
        <option value="room1">Room 1:</option>
        <option value="room2">Room 2:</option>
</form>
```

I want to set up an action so that when an option is selected to direct the user to the `checkin.php` page without them having to use a submit button. I've been told to use `onChange`, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Please modify the last part of your post.  I have no idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Should "New Room" be a submittable option too? and should it auto-submit using the onchange? You should be aware that you cannot *change* to the same option that the select was on at page load so whichever option is the default will not be accessible. I'd recommend using a place-holder eg: with no value and text of: "Choose a room"

Comment: Please don't. _If_ you want to react to a change event, load new content into the page _and leave the dropdown there_. I hate unexpected reloads. Especially if I have to navigate back because I've misclicked. Especially if the page and/or my device is slow as hell.

Answer (score 5):

```
<select name="roomname" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    ...
</select>
```

How about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple function. It should be generic enough to work for other forms too:

```
<head>
  <script>
      function submitForm(elem) {
          if (elem.value) {
              elem.form.submit();
          }
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="checkin.php" method="post">
    <select name="roomname" onchange="submitForm(this)">  
      <option value="">New Room:</option>
      <option value="room1">Room 1:</option>
      <option value="room2">Room 2:</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>
```

The function checks that you have a value in the select IE you haven't changed to the place-holder entry. If `New Room` is not a place holder I'd suggest making one otherwise it won't be accessible, with or without the check for a value.

Basically the functions stops the following behavior:

1. You go to this form and choose "Room 1"
2. The form is auto submitted and you go to `checkin.php`
3. You change your mind and hit the *Back* button
4. The browser remembers the state of the form and the "Room 1" option is still selected
5. You change the drop-down back to "New Room" and the form detects the change and submits.

**EDIT** : Also note you are missing a closing `</select>` tag.